# atching kube-system aws-node daemonset failed with invalid json

Tags: kubernetes, patch, kubectl

To add a new environment variable to my aws-node daemonset to disable snat on eks nodes in a private subnet i tried to patch the saemonset by using kubectl. I dont want use edit because I want to add these variable with ansible later.

```sh
$ kubectl patch daemonset -n kube-system aws-node --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/1/env/4", "value": {"name": "AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_EXTERNALSNAT", "value": "true" } }]'

The  "" is invalid
```

```sh
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.8-eks-7c34c0", GitCommit:"7c34c0d2f2d0f11f397d55a46945193a0e22d8f3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-01T22:49:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```sh
$ kubectl get daemonset -n kube-system aws-node -ojson
```

```
{
    "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
    "kind": "DaemonSet",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"extensions/v1beta1\",\"kind\":\"DaemonSet\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"k8s-app\":\"aws-node\"},\"name\":\"aws-node\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\"},\"spec\":{\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"k8s-app\":\"aws-node\"}},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod\":\"\"},\"labels\":{\"k8s-app\":\"aws-node\"}},\"spec\":{\"affinity\":{\"nodeAffinity\":{\"requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution\":{\"nodeSelectorTerms\":[{\"matchExpressions\":[{\"key\":\"beta.kubernetes.io/os\",\"operator\":\"In\",\"values\":[\"linux\"]},{\"key\":\"beta.kubernetes.io/arch\",\"operator\":\"In\",\"values\":[\"amd64\"]}]}]}}},\"containers\":[{\"env\":[{\"name\":\"AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_LOGLEVEL\",\"value\":\"DEBUG\"},{\"name\":\"MY_NODE_NAME\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"spec.nodeName\"}}},{\"name\":\"WATCH_NAMESPACE\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.namespace\"}}}],\"image\":\"602401143452.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/amazon-k8s-cni:v1.3.2\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"Always\",\"name\":\"aws-node\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":61678,\"name\":\"metrics\"}],\"resources\":{\"requests\":{\"cpu\":\"10m\"}},\"securityContext\":{\"privileged\":true},\"volumeMounts\":[{\"mountPath\":\"/host/opt/cni/bin\",\"name\":\"cni-bin-dir\"},{\"mountPath\":\"/host/etc/cni/net.d\",\"name\":\"cni-net-dir\"},{\"mountPath\":\"/host/var/log\",\"name\":\"log-dir\"},{\"mountPath\":\"/var/run/docker.sock\",\"name\":\"dockersock\"}]}],\"hostNetwork\":true,\"serviceAccountName\":\"aws-node\",\"tolerations\":[{\"operator\":\"Exists\"}],\"volumes\":[{\"hostPath\":{\"path\":\"/opt/cni/bin\"},\"name\":\"cni-bin-dir\"},{\"hostPath\":{\"path\":\"/etc/cni/net.d\"},\"name\":\"cni-net-dir\"},{\"hostPath\":{\"path\":\"/var/log\"},\"name\":\"log-dir\"},{\"hostPath\":{\"path\":\"/var/run/docker.sock\"},\"name\":\"dockersock\"}]}},\"updateStrategy\":{\"type\":\"RollingUpdate\"}}}\n"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-05-15T06:16:57Z",
        "generation": 3,
        "labels": {
            "k8s-app": "aws-node"
        },
        "name": "aws-node",
        "namespace": "kube-system",
        "resourceVersion": "527483",
        "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/daemonsets/aws-node",
        "uid": "0ae27eda-76d9-11e9-a0b4-02731f2710d4"
    },
    "spec": {
        "revisionHistoryLimit": 10,
        "selector": {
            "matchLabels": {
                "k8s-app": "aws-node"
            }
        },
        "template": {
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod": ""
                },
                "creationTimestamp": null,
                "labels": {
                    "k8s-app": "aws-node"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "affinity": {
                    "nodeAffinity": {
                        "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": {
                            "nodeSelectorTerms": [
                                {
                                    "matchExpressions": [
                                        {
                                            "key": "beta.kubernetes.io/os",
                                            "operator": "In",
                                            "values": [
                                                "linux"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "beta.kubernetes.io/arch",
                                            "operator": "In",
                                            "values": [
                                                "amd64"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "env": [
                            {
                                "name": "AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_LOGLEVEL",
                                "value": "DEBUG"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "MY_NODE_NAME",
                                "valueFrom": {
                                    "fieldRef": {
                                        "apiVersion": "v1",
                                        "fieldPath": "spec.nodeName"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "WATCH_NAMESPACE",
                                "valueFrom": {
                                    "fieldRef": {
                                        "apiVersion": "v1",
                                        "fieldPath": "metadata.namespace"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "image": "602401143452.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/amazon-k8s-cni:v1.3.2",
                        "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
                        "name": "aws-node",
                        "ports": [
                            {
                                "containerPort": 61678,
                                "hostPort": 61678,
                                "name": "metrics",
                                "protocol": "TCP"
                            }
                        ],
                        "resources": {
                            "requests": {
                                "cpu": "10m"
                            }
                        },
                        "securityContext": {
                            "privileged": true
                        },
                        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                        "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                        "volumeMounts": [
                            {
                                "mountPath": "/host/opt/cni/bin",
                                "name": "cni-bin-dir"
                            },
                            {
                                "mountPath": "/host/etc/cni/net.d",
                                "name": "cni-net-dir"
                            },
                            {
                                "mountPath": "/host/var/log",
                                "name": "log-dir"
                            },
                            {
                                "mountPath": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                                "name": "dockersock"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                "hostNetwork": true,
                "restartPolicy": "Always",
                "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
                "securityContext": {},
                "serviceAccount": "aws-node",
                "serviceAccountName": "aws-node",
                "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
                "tolerations": [
                    {
                        "operator": "Exists"
                    }
                ],
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "hostPath": {
                            "path": "/opt/cni/bin",
                            "type": ""
                        },
                        "name": "cni-bin-dir"
                    },
                    {
                        "hostPath": {
                            "path": "/etc/cni/net.d",
                            "type": ""
                        },
                        "name": "cni-net-dir"
                    },
                    {
                        "hostPath": {
                            "path": "/var/log",
                            "type": ""
                        },
                        "name": "log-dir"
                    },
                    {
                        "hostPath": {
                            "path": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                            "type": ""
                        },
                        "name": "dockersock"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "templateGeneration": 3,
        "updateStrategy": {
            "rollingUpdate": {
                "maxUnavailable": 1
            },
            "type": "RollingUpdate"
        }
    },
    "status": {
        "currentNumberScheduled": 4,
        "desiredNumberScheduled": 4,
        "numberMisscheduled": 0,
        "numberReady": 0,
        "numberUnavailable": 4,
        "observedGeneration": 3,
        "updatedNumberScheduled": 4
    }
}
```

I expect a new added environment variable to disable snat for eks worker in a private subnet

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use an older kubectl version. The version of your kubectl client might be too new for the Kubernetes API server that you are trying to reach. [The docs say](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/version-skew-policy/)

```
kubelet must not be newer than kube-apiserver, and may be up to two minor versions older.
```

I would try using the same version in both the client and the server. To download an specific kubectl version

```
$ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.11.8/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
$ chmod +x ./kubectl
```

and then try again your command.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the array index. It should be 0 not 1. So after container

```
kubectl patch daemonset -n kube-system aws-node --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/4", "value": {"name": "AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_EXTERNALSNAT", "value": "true" } }]'
```

It worked for me. Thanks for the command. It was pretty close.

Im actually using it to enable CNI custom network in EKS.
If anyone needs it...

```
kubectl patch daemonset -n kube-system aws-node --type='json' -p='[{"op":"add","path":"/spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/0", "value":{"name":"AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_CUSTOM_NETWORK_CFG","value":"true"}}]'
```